# Read text file line by line and Count specific word for particular values from a line and save the line above that

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The below data is saved in a text file. Now, I want to start counting the "FBC = " and want to stop counting when it contains some specific value and save the line above that "FBC" word.

```
Block = 150

Erase time= 1830, Cycle= 0

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,FFFFFFFF,FFBBFFFF,FFFFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 265, 

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FFFFFF8F,FDFBFFFF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 355, 

Read time= 1623, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFCC,

Page = 9600 FBC = 505, 

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFDD,

Page = 9600 FBC = 642, 

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFC,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFEE,

Page = 9600 FBC = 718, 

Block = 150

Erase time= 1830, Cycle= 0

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFF,FFBBFFFF,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFAAA,

Page = 9600 FBC = 235, 

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFF,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFBBB,

Page = 9600 FBC = 310, 

Read time= 1623, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFCCC,

Page = 9600 FBC = 445, 

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFDDD,

Page = 9600 FBC = 565, 

Read time= 1617, Cycle= 1,DFF7FFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFFBF,

Page = 9600 FBC = 680,
```

Please help me to count `FBC` with particular values.
Please note, there will be more sections like these.

I tried the below-mentioned code, and the O/p I am getting is

```
3

4

['Read time= 1623', ' Cycle= 1', 'DFFFBFFF', 'FFBBFFFF', 'FCFFFF8F', 'FDFBFFCC', '']
['Read time= 1623', ' Cycle= 1', 'DFFFFFFC', 'FFBBFFFB', 'FFEFFF8F', 'FDFBFCCC', ''].
```

My expected result is also included below.

```
    with open('Test.txt') as f:
        count, found = 0, False
        pat = re.compile(r'\bFBC\s*=\s*(\d+)')
        P_Stress = []
        TotalCount = []
        for line in f:
            line1 = line.strip()
            if line1:
                if line1.startswith('Block'):
                    count, found = 0, False
                elif 'FBC' in line1 and not found:
                    count += 1
                    num = pat.search(line1).groups()
                    num = ''.join(map(str, num))
                    if int(num) >= 500:
                        found = True
                        print count            
    with open('Online_StackOverflow_2.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                if line.startswith('Block'):
                    Rcount, found = 0, False
                elif 'Read time' in line and not found:
                    Rcount += 1
                    for i in range(0, len(TotalCount), 1):     
                        if Rcount==TotalCount[i]:
                            xx=line.split(",");
                            print xx
                        break;
```

Expected output: it should stop counting when `FBC > 500`. So, for 1st Section, output will be `count = 3` and save DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFCC,
For 2nd section, output will be `count = 4` and save DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFDDD,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. Thanks to my friend & @RomanPerekhrest:

```
    with open('Test.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                if line.startswith('Block'):
                    Rcount, found = 0, False
                elif 'Read time' in line and not found:
                    readLine = line
                    Rcount += 1
                    nextLine = next(f)
                    if 'FBC' in nextLine and not found:
                        num = pat.search(nextLine).groups()
                        num = ''.join(map(str, num)) 
                        if int(num) >= 500:
                            found = True
                            print Rcount
                            print readLine
                            TotalCount.append(count)
```

O/P:

3

Read time= 1623, Cycle= 1,DFFFBFFF,FFBBFFFF,FCFFFF8F,FDFBFFCC,

4

Read time= 1624, Cycle= 1,DFFFFFFC,FFBBFFFB,FFEFFF8F,FDFBFDDD,